# Send and receive data between Android phone and smart TV (LG, Sony) supports DIAL

Tags: android, google-cast, upnp, ssdp

I'm developing an Android application to connects and cast Video to Smart TV that supports DIAL (like Chromecast). Currently, I can discover and launch my application on Smart TV from mobile (sample here: https://github.com/entertailion/DIAL). But I don't know how to send and receive data between my applications on Android phone and Smart TV.
I heard that There are proprietary protocol called RAMP to do media control are sent over web socket connection. But I don't know how to implement this.
What should I do in Android application and in Smart TV application?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Choose a "smart TV" vendor and ask them.

Answer (score -1):

Take a look at http://connectsdk.com/. For Samsung TVs please refer http://multiscreen.samsung.com/.